# How to sequence STATUS (IGNORING DUPLICATES IN BETWEEN)

Tags: t-sql

I have a table containing Customer ID and Status. I would want to sequence the Status order only when there is a change in the status.
Below is the table displaying the current data in columns CUSTOMER_ID AND CUT_STATUS. I would want to create or get the REQUIRED_SEQUENCE COLUMN.

[image]

Comment: we also need the column(s) you have used to create this sorting

Comment: The rows in a table have no order. Do you have, as George Menoutis inquired, a column that you have chosen not to share, e.g. a `DateTime` column like `Status_Changed_On`? Without an explicit order for the rows there is no way to determine `REQUIRED_SEQUENCE`.

Comment: You are right, I've tried to modify the question and omitted a column containing Identity values in the table. The Order can be achieved by Grouping the CUSTOMER_ID and using Identity column for sequence.
I've posted my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's address your demo data. When asking questions like this it's important to provide good DDL/DML which is easily reproducible. A good way to do this is to use table variables. They're easy to setup, and there's nothing to clean up afterwards. Posting images of data is not very helpful, as anyone who's going to attempt help you first needs to turn that into something they can use.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (CUSTOMER_ID INT, CUST_STATUS NVARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @TABLE (CUSTOMER_ID, CUST_STATUS) VALUES
(111, 'ACTIVE'), (111, 'ACTIVE'), (111, 'ACTIVE'), (111, 'ACTIVE'),
(111, 'ACTIVE'), (222, 'ACTIVE'), (222, 'PENDING'), (222, 'PENDING'),
(222, 'ACTIVE'), (222, 'ACTIVE'), (222, 'ACTIVE');
```

As others in the comments have pointed out, there is no order to this data. Just because you can run a select and *usually* get the data back in a specific order doesn't mean you always will, and relying on that **will** cause you problems. I'm going to assume there are additional columns in your table which can be used to provide an order, but since I don't have them I'm going to cheat a little to get you to the desired answer:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, CUST_STATUS, SUM(Cnter) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY rn) AS REQUIRED_SEQUENCE
  FROM (
        SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, CUST_STATUS, CASE WHEN CUST_STATUS = LAG(CUST_STATUS,1) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) THEN 0 
                       WHEN LAG(CUST_STATUS,1) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) IS NULL THEN 1 
                       WHEN CUST_STATUS <> LAG(CUST_STATUS,1) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) THEN 1 END AS Cnter,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn
          FROM @TABLE
       ) a
```

| CUSTOMER_ID | CUST_STATUS | REQUIRED_SEQUENCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 111 | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 111 | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 111 | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 111 | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 222 | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 222 | PENDING | 2 |
| 222 | PENDING | 2 |
| 222 | ACTIVE | 3 |
| 222 | ACTIVE | 3 |
| 222 | ACTIVE | 3 |

What's going on here? First we're using the windowed function `LAG` to determine if the previous row belongs to this set and fetching it's value. windowed functions have an `OVER` clause, which states how the window is defined. In this case we're telling it to create a new window for each group of `CUSTOMER_ID`, we're also telling it the window should be in order of `(SELECT 1)` which is a rotten kluge that says *what ever order you like* (this is where your order definition from the real data would go).

Now we can see if the previous row belongs to the same group, and compare it's value to the current rows value for `CUST_STATUS`. If it's `NULL` we're going to set it to 1, as this is the first status for that group. If it's different we're also going to set it to 1. If it's the same as the previous row we'll set it to 0.

I also put a `ROW_NUMBER()` windowed function in the select, so we can have an order in the outer query. You can disregard this when you're using the actual column(s) to order the data. Just replace it with those columns instead.

In the outer query we're just selecting the results, and using `SUM` as a windowed function, again partitioned by `CUSTOMER_ID` and ordered by the `ROW_NUMBER()` we generated (replace that with your actual column(s)). This gives us a running total of the rows which start a new group of statuses, and matches the output you requested.

Comment: I agree to your approach and explanation regarding the question. The scenario has couple problems which is the result doesn't have a order. I have taken a different approach. Here's what I've done,
1. Load the current data into a Temp table with identity column, (To create a column with sequence order )
2. Instead of using Lead or Lag, I've done self join between the 2 tables, with a case statement. Then using aggregator SUM to build the REQUIRED_SEQUENCE column. 

This was quicker for my scenario. But I agree with your solution.
Thanks